# Start by creating a new Next.js project using create-next-app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a new Next.js project using "create-next-app" but I'm getting the following errors. How can I run this command?

PS C:\Users\gizem> npx create-next-app@latest my-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\gizem\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\gizem\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\gizem\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-31T08_18_34_114Z-debug-0.log

I checked if npm is available but there is no problem. Changing the index and trying again did not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem related to npm not being able to find a file or directory. It doesn't necessarily mean that there is an issue with npm itself, but rather it might be a problem with the way your Node.js environment is configured or the specific directory you are trying to create your Next.js project in.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. **Update npm and Node.js**: Ensure that you have the latest version of npm and Node.js installed on your system. You can update npm and Node.js using the following commands:

   ```
   npm install -g npm@latest
   npm install -g n
   n latest
   ```
2. **Clear npm cache**: Sometimes, issues can be resolved by clearing the npm cache. You can do this by running the following command:

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. **Create the Next.js app in a different directory**: Try creating your Next.js app in a different directory to see if the issue is specific to the directory you were using. For example:

   ```
   npx create-next-app@latest my-new-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint
   ```
4. **Check for environmental issues**: Ensure there are no issues with your environmental variables or permissions that may be causing the problem. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to create files and directories in the target location.
5. **Use yarn**: If you continue to experience issues with `npx` and `npm`, you can also try using `yarn` to create a Next.js app. First, you'll need to install Yarn globally (if not already installed):

   ```
   npm install -g yarn
   ```

   Then, you can create a Next.js app using Yarn:

   ```
   yarn create next-app my-app
   ```
6. **Check the logs**: The error message mentions a log file that you can check for more details. You can examine the log file located at `C:\Users\gizem\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-31T08_18_34_114Z-debug-0.log` for additional information about the issue. This log may provide more specific information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands one by one

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm cache clean -f
```

try again `create-next-app@latest`

if this doesnot work, try renaming your file name

Answer (score 0):

sometimes after installing node js and npm, system needs restart, try doing that and npx create-next-app@latest my-app

hope this helps